# How to connect RAILS with Red5 Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, red5, jrubyonrails, red5pro

I am trying to develop an Application with Red5 Server.

I did some of the steps:

1. I set up the Red5 server into our local machine (Ubuntu)
2. I installed the MangoDB database locally with Rails configuration.
3. Now My problem is: I am using Jruby(Java Ruby) as server programming. I am not able to connect my Rails to Red5 server. Is there any documentation?